# Row to column but 2by2

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In excel 2013, I have a data from `F46` to `FI46` almost 160 cells in row 46. Now I want these value in sheet2 in the following pattern

```
ColumnD ColumnE
F46     G46
H46     I46
...     ...
...     ...
...     ...
FH46    FI46
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula in column D to get the first value:

```
=INDEX($F$46:$FI$46,1,1+(ROWS(C$1:C1)-1)*2)
```

And this one in column E to get the second value:

```
=INDEX($F$46:$FI$46,1,2+(ROWS(C$1:C1)-1)*2)
```

And then drag the two down to get the subsequent values from row 46.

If they are in different sheets, just put the relevant sheet name before `$F$46:$FI$46`. E.g. if the row 46 with data is in Sheet1, use `'Sheet1'!$F$46:$FI$46`.